# How to write a script which executes certain commands on terminal?

Tags: shell-script

There are certain sequences of commands I usually type in a console one after the other, e.g.

```
adb devices
adb uninstall com.package.abc
cd myProjectDir
meteor reset
rm -f -r .meteor/local
meteor run android-device
```

How can I write a script which lets me execute all (or at least a part of) these commands in one row (e.g. `./batchRunMeteor`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways:

A) run some number of commands in one row, linked with semicolons

```
adb devices; adb uninstall com.package.abc; cd myProjectDir; meteor reset; rm -f -r .meteor/local; meteor run android-device
```

Here I've kept the original "intent" of simple sequential execution. One recommendation would be to run subsequent commands only if the preceding one(s) succeeded; that's accomplished with `&&` :

```
adb devices && adb uninstall com.package.abc && cd myProjectDir && meteor reset && rm -f -r .meteor/local && meteor run android-device
```

B) create an alias

```
alias batchRunMeteor='adb devices; adb uninstall com.package.abc; cd myProjectDir; meteor reset; rm -f -r .meteor/local; meteor run android-device'
# or use the && method:
alias batchRunMeteor='adb devices && adb uninstall com.package.abc && cd myProjectDir && meteor reset && rm -f -r .meteor/local && meteor run android-device'
batchRunMeteor
```

C) create a shell script

```
cat > batchRunMeteor << EOF
adb devices
adb uninstall com.package.abc
cd myProjectDir
meteor reset
rm -f -r .meteor/local
meteor run android-device
EOF

chmod u+x batchRunMeteor 
./batchRunMeteor
```

The shell script can also use `&&` as desired.

Comment: thank you Jeff. can you please explain c:), particularly the first line (cat > batchRunMeteor << EOF)?

Comment: sure; that's just one way to get those lines into a file; feel free to use your favorite editor instead. The "<<" redirect syntax says to take the remaining lines until you see the indicator again; here, the I called indicator "EOF", but you can call it anything you want. The ">" redirection puts those lines into a file of the given name (batchRunMeteor).